# Spark failing HDFS writes

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm using HDFS as a checkpoint directory for some spark jobs but sometimes they just start to fail writing to HDFS.

The error message in Spark is

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /streaming/example-query/state/0/0/temp--1233934526312931692 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1547)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:724)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
```

The namenode prints the following error messages:

```
17/12/20 08:49:52 WARN blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 3 (unavailableStorages=[], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) For more information, please enable DEBUG log level on org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy
17/12/20 08:49:52 WARN protocol.BlockStoragePolicy: Failed to place enough replicas: expected size is 1 but only 0 storage types can be selected (replication=3, selected=[], unavailable=[DISK], removed=[DISK], policy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]})
17/12/20 08:49:52 WARN blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 1 to reach 3 (unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) All required storage types are unavailable:  unavailableStorages=[DISK], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}
17/12/20 08:49:52 INFO hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1345727054_271990505{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-33af5c05-f2fd-4f9d-9e13-96f9fa64fbeb:NORMAL:172.20.95.127:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-57ecb9a7-a853-42d9-a213-01389658305d:NORMAL:172.20.69.2:50010|RBW]]} for /streaming/example-query/state/0/199/550.snapshot.temp--5780088563343554929
17/12/20 08:49:52 WARN blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy: Failed to place enough replicas, still in need of 2 to reach 3 (unavailableStorages=[], storagePolicy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]}, newBlock=true) For more information, please enable DEBUG log level on org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy
17/12/20 08:49:52 WARN protocol.BlockStoragePolicy: Failed to place enough replicas: expected size is 2 but only 0 storage types can be selected (replication=3, selected=[], unavailable=[DISK], removed=[DISK, DISK], policy=BlockStoragePolicy{HOT:7, storageTypes=[DISK], creationFallbacks=[], replicationFallbacks=[ARCHIVE]})
```

At some point it just starts to cool down again and runs smoothly.

Am I running into some resource shortage here? I've checked disk space, inodes cpu and memory and they seem to be fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes actually, the datanodes got out of sync by a lot. Mostly delete operations, but millions of them. I solved the problem by sharding the HDFS cluster and using a interval for my structured streaming job.

Comment: would be great if you can add an answer with a bit more details. I am stuck on this issue myself.

Comment: Sorry @aandis, I just remembered what the actual problem was. I put it down as an answer. To see if that's your problem, try recording iotop and htop output and check for `du` process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it was a problem of hadoop with my setup.
The datanodes got too out of sync to accept any more files because they were too slow.

The datanodes were too slow because they were using `du` to check filesystem usage and I had a lot of small files (spark checkpoints). Since my volumes were on a separate volume anyway, I changed it to using `df` by specifying the variable `fs.getspaceused.classname` in the core config as `org.apache.hadoop.fs.DFCachingGetSpaceUsed`.

Comment: Very nice, we had the same issue but were ending up "patching" it on the system level. Your solution seems more accurate, though.